# Not seeing flutter screen class in firebase console

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to see when a user opens a specific screen i my app. But the only screen classes i can see under events/screen_view is *MainActivity* and *FlutterViewController*.

In the app I have the following code:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
```

at the top

```dart
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
```

in the state of a stateful widget

```dart
onPressed: (){
  analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'Example');
}
```

inside a button that opens a page

Have I missed something, or am I looking at the wrong place in the console?

Comment: hey, any luck with that?

Comment: I ended up doing it a completely different way as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55831114