# Instance member 'setCurrentScreen' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics to my flutter app to display different screen names on the dashboard. I used a method that I found here on stackoverflow in this link:
[How do I track Flutter screens in Firebase analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830575/how-do-i-track-flutter-screens-in-firebase-analytics)

I added this code in a separate file:

```
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

// A Navigator observer that notifies RouteAwares of changes to state of their Route
final routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

mixin RouteAwareAnalytics<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T>
    implements RouteAware {
  AnalyticsRoute get route;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute<dynamic>);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {}

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Called when the top route has been popped off,
    // and the current route shows up.
    _setCurrentScreen(route);
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // Called when the current route has been pushed.
    _setCurrentScreen(route);
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {}

  Future<void> _setCurrentScreen(AnalyticsRoute analyticsRoute) {
    print('Setting current screen to $analyticsRoute');
    return FirebaseAnalytics.**setCurrentScreen**(
      screenName: screenName(analyticsRoute),
      screenClassOverride: screenClass(analyticsRoute),
    );
  }
}

enum AnalyticsRoute { screenName }

String screenClass(AnalyticsRoute route) {
  switch (route) {
    case AnalyticsRoute.screenName:
      return 'screenName';
  }
  throw ArgumentError.notNull('route');
}

String screenName(AnalyticsRoute route) {
  switch (route) {
    case AnalyticsRoute.screenName:
      return '/screenName';
  }
  throw ArgumentError.notNull('route');
}
```

I then added the route observer in the screen that I want to track.
The setCurrentScreen method is not working well and the app is not building. Any suggestions on what I could do to build it.

Comment: It should be `FirebaseAnalytics().setCurrentScreen` and not `FirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen`

Comment: The class 'FirebaseAnalytics' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'FirebaseAnalytics'…… This is the error it is giving now.

Comment: Try this `FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setCurrentScreen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FlutterFire documentation on [screen tracking](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/usage#screen-tracking):

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance
  .setCurrentScreen(
    screenName: 'Products'
  );
```